# java Error parsing JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I'm doing a json parser for java. I receive the json as string and then i try to get all the keys-value

Here is my Json string

```
 { "Message":{"field": [ {"bit":2,"name":"AAA"}, {"bit":3,"name":"BBB"}]}}
```

And here is my parser:

```
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); //result contains the json                 
                JSONArray info = jObject.getJSONArray("field");
                for (int i = 0 ; i < info.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
                    while (keys.hasNext()) { //I use key - value cause the json can change
                        String key =  keys.next();
                        System.out.println("Key: " + key + "\tValue: " + obj.get(key));
                    }
                }
```

But everytime that i run the code i get:

```
Error parsing json org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["field"] not found.
```

And i guess the field its a JsonArray... Am i wrong?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You are one level too deep wanted to get `field` from your `jObject`.
You need to do :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject jMsg = jObject.getJSONObject("Message");               
JSONArray info = jMsg.getJSONArray("field");
```

Answer (score 2):

**You need to get get `JSONArray` `field` from `JSONObjct` `Message`**

```
String result = "{ \"Message\":{\"field\": [ {\"bit\":2,\"name\":\"AAA\"}, {\"bit\":3,\"name\":\"BBB\"}]}}";
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("Message"); //result contains the json
JSONArray info = jObject.getJSONArray("field");
for (int i = 0 ; i < info.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = info.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) { //I use key - value cause the json can change
        String key =  keys.next();
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + "\tValue: " + obj.get(key));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Key: name   Value: AAA
Key: bit    Value: 2
Key: name   Value: BBB
Key: bit    Value: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        String result = "{ \"Message\":{\"field\": [ {\"bit\":2,\"name\":\"AAA\"}, {\"bit\":3,\"name\":\"BBB\"}]}}";

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); //result contains the json
    JSONArray info = jObject.getJSONObject("Message").getJSONArray("field");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < info.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = info.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) { //I use key - value cause the json can change
            String key =  keys.next();
            System.out.println("Key: " + key + "\tValue: " + obj.get(key));
        }
    }
```